# Playwright new browser context over CDP, or record video otherwise

Tags: android, google-chrome, playwright, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to record a video of a Playwright session of a Chrome browser connected to my laptop and running via `connectOverCDP`:

```
const browser = await chromium.connectOverCDP(...);
const context = await browser.newContext({recordVideo: ...});
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
browser.newContext: Protocol error (Target.createBrowserContext): Failed to create browser context.
```

Connecting to an existing context via CDP works fine, but Playwright does not support record video of an existing session.

What can solve this problem, or help me record a browser session video otherwise?